# Verifying event handler code executed

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, .net-4.0, tdd

I have code very similar to this but cannot work out how I test whether an event handler occured.

```
public class MyClass : MyAbstractClass
{ 
  IFileSystem FileSystem;

  public MyClass(IFileSystem myFileSys)
  {
    FileSystem = myFileSys;
    FileSystem.EventHit += new EventHandler(FileSystem_EventHit);
  }

  public void FileSystem_EventHit(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    //Testing base.OnOutput is not possible which I wont go into
    base.OnOutput("EventHit");
  }
}
```

Testing code is here:

```
    [Test]
    public void DoSomething_WhenCalled_EventFired()
    {
         var mock = new Moq.Mock<IFileSystem>();

         MyClass plugin = new MyClass (mock.Object);

         mock.Object.DoSomething();

         mock.Raise(x => x.EventHit += null, new EventArgs());

        //Verify/Assert that MyClass handled and did something in the event handler

    }
```

Comment: Can you give details WRT base.OnOutput, maybe it is testable?

Comment: MyAbstractClass is legacy and so is MyClass therefore its messy and requires a lot of setup to test so I was hoping that there was some way to test without having to verify base.OnOutput

Comment: A common scenario; retrospectively writing unit tests.  I'm not aware of any shortcuts.  Whenever I come up against this I find myself refactoring the code so that it can be unit tested.

Comment: @MylesMcDonnell Wish I had that option :)

Comment: sounds ugly, so you have to write unit tests without making the code testable, ouch. An imperfect but pragmatic approach is to accept that certain types are tightly coupled and define your test boundaries around these types.  Not strictly unit tests, but might have some value for you in enabling tests with a minimum of changes?

Comment: @MylesMcDonnell I'm going to have to assume that the legacy code works but still have the ability to test dependencies. The problem here is that the dependency raises an event in which legacy code is called and I can't work out a way to test it. I guess I can test that there is a eventhandler/subscriber but that's all I can think of which isnt great

Comment: You don't really need to verify that the event mechanisms in .NET work, do you? Wouldn't an appropriate test be that the constructor of `MyClass` added an event handler for `EventHit`?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I guess but I do not know hot to do that in Moq. Please enlighten me! However surely the best way of testing is to verify behaviour in the object under test. This is my problem though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As verifying something in the event handler would mean trying to test legacy code the option I went with was to test that the event fired from within the concrete type and not a mock.

```
[Test]
public void DoSomething_WhenCalled_EventFired()
{

  FileSystem fs = new FileSystem(mock.Object, timerMock.Object);

  bool WasItHit = false;
  fs.EventHit += delegate { WasItHit = true; };

  fs.DoSomething(); //This should call the event

  Assert.IsTrue(WasItHit);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way I can think of is to just add your own handler in the test method, which should suffice I would think?

```
[Test]
    public void DoSomething_WhenCalled_EventFired()
    {
         var mock = new Moq.Mock<IFileSystem>();
         bool isHit = false;

         mock.EventHit += (s, e) =>
         {
            isHit = true;
         };

         MyClass plugin = new MyClass (mock.Object);

         mock.Object.DoSomething();

         mock.Raise(x => x.EventHit += null, new EventArgs());

         Assert.IsTrue(isHit);

    }
```

Comment: That will assert that the mock raised the event, it won't confirm that MyClass.FileSystem_EventHit was called or verify what happened as a result.

Answer (score 0):

You need to inject a mock of whatever gets called as a result of the event handler invocation and verify it.  Your comment says you can't test base base.OnOutput, but it seems to me that is exactly what you need to do.

Comment: And that's where the problem lies! The abstract class and mostly MyClass is legacy code and its a nightmare to test

Answer (score 0):

Basically testing of a fact that method was called is not a valid test case, you should test a logic/behaviour behind a method. Obviously with a given event handler there is nothing to test, this is why a task looks not trivial.

Try out formulate in few words what are you trying to test, which test case. For instance

> MyClass switches a state into the `State==Hit` whilst
>   `FileSystem.EventHit` event.

Comment: I agree but MyClass is acting as a input/ouput type class so something comes in calls DoSomething which it does, fires an event and does an output

Comment: What does it do the output to, Jon? If it's another dependency, then mock the dependency that MyClass, or the base class uses to do the output and verify that a call was made to output using that dependency.

Comment: Yup I would do but its all legacy code and is a nightmare to setup

Comment: @Jon : right, writing unit tests for the legacy code this is nightmare as well

Answer (score 0):

To do that you probably need a flag in MyClass indicating that event occured. I know, this will be just for purpose of running a test but sometimes is good to have something like that.